# Deploying Nuxt SSR Universal App on Vercel serverless function

Tags: nuxt.js, vercel

I'm trying to host a universal ssr app built with nuxt 2 on vercel.

Here's the [Project Repo](https://github.com/MuhammadM1998/NuxtBnB), The project total size is about 6mb

But when i try to build vercel it gives this error

`Error: The Serverless Function "index" is 124.58mb which exceeds the maximum size limit of 50mb. Learn More: https://vercel.link/serverless-function-size`

a screenshot of the error

[image: Vercel Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing more to add here, a serverless function is meant to lightweight and with a very few dependencies.

While a Nuxt2 app comes with node modules and a lot of things. This is not the correct usage of a serverless function.

Also, if you're using `ssr` with `target: 'server'`, you will need a node.js instance running anyways, so Vercel does not fit either. Something like Heroku is more adapted.
If you only use SSG (`target: 'static'), it may be fine.

Comment: I made the project following a course, the tutor also hosts the project on vercel. My app is bigger because I used alternatives like mapbox instead of google maps and tomtom search instead of google places and firebase auth instead of google oauth. This is the course project repo: `https://github.com/MasteringNuxt/NuxtBnB`. I noticed he has a fewer dependieces than my project's. Could this be the issue?

Comment: I tried deploying to heroku as you advised and it worked without any problems. I also didn't know that the size in the error message was the size of my project (specifically the big node_modules). Thank you very much for the clarification

Comment: @MuhammadMahmoud hosting a Nuxt app on a serverless function is probably not a good idea (this is not what this is meant for, regarding the usage). Dependencies are a concern, also you could send the built project rather than installing it. Overall, serverless functions usually have a size limit yeah. Glad that Heroku worked tho!

Comment: I'll search for sending the built project and I'll appreciate it if you helped me with links too. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

I know it's been some months since the question was answered but I wanted to contribute as well, having finished the same Nuxt course as well.

I changed the vercel-builder version to 0.22.1 as proposed on this issue on github: https://github.com/nuxt/vercel-builder/issues/633

```json
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "nuxt.config.js",
      "use": "@nuxtjs/vercel-builder@0.22.1",
      //...
    }
  ]
}
```

As for November 2022 this solved the issue.

Comment: Also passing some dependencies to dev dependencies reduces Serverless Function size.